# When is a Deadlock not a Deadlock?

Tags: t-sql

I'm asking this question because I'm getting a deadlock from time to time that I don't understand.

This is the scenario:

Stored Procedure that updates table A:

```
UPDATE A
SET    A.Column = @SomeValue
WHERE  A.ID     = @ID
```

Stored Procedure that inserts into a temp table #temp:

```
INSERT INTO #temp (Column1,Column2)

SELECT B.Column1, A.Column2

FROM B

INNER JOIN A
  ON A.ID = B.ID

WHERE  B.Code IN ('Something','SomethingElse')
```

I see that there could possibly be a lock wait but I fail to see how a deadlock would occur, am I missing something obvious?

**EDIT:**

The SPs that I typed here are obviously simplified versions but I'm using the columns involved. The structure of both tables would be:

```
CREATE TABLE A (ID IDENTITY
                   CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY,
                Column VARCHAR (100))


CREATE TABLE B (ID IDENTITY
                   CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY,
                Code VARCHAR (100))
```

Comment: `update` waiting for `insert into` to finish and `insert into` waiting for `update` to finish? Both waiting for the other to finish!

Comment: If both Update and Insert were against the same table, unless the Insert statement tries to set an exclusive lock on ALL the tables involved and not only on the #temp one

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/08/deadlocked.html

Comment: Is `A.ID` indexed? In fact what are the complete table structures involved and deadlock graph?

Comment: @Michael Fredrickson: Great read, same problem that I'm having and the solution is the one that I'm implementing, unfortunately the problem is not explained, I'm reading through all the comments to see if someone has insight on the cause. Thanks :)

Comment: Read the whole thread and found no conscensus, even the people that were angered for such a "dumb question on deadlocking" did not provide an answer, just distructive critisism. I'm going to appli the (NOLOCK) hint to the select SP and  that should solve the problem. Thanks to all that read and commented :)

Comment: I'd say toss a Profiler trace on it and capture the deadlock graph that comes out.  Though you'll need a tall beer afterwards from reading it, that'll show you exactly what objects & locks forced the deadlock.  For good measure, you can also trap lock escalations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this since its causeing locks specify for the tables name the table hint and keyword:

```
WITH(NOLOCK)
```

So some thing like this for your scenario:

```
    INSERT INTO #temp (Column1,Column2)

    SELECT B.Column1, A.Column2

FROM B WITH(NOLCOK)

INNER JOIN A WITH(NOLOCK)
  ON A.ID = B.ID

WHERE  B.Code IN ('Something','SomethingElse')
```

See how you go then.

You can lookup table hint also for tsql, sql server to see which one suits you best. The one I specified NOLCOK will not cause locks and also it will skip locked rows as some other process is using them, so if you dont care you can use it.

I am not sure with temp tables but you can also use table hints with INSERT, INSERT INTO  WITH(TABLE_HINT).

Comment: Hi Pasha, I did end up using the (NOLOCK) option which solved the problem (Please se comments on the question, there is a link to an excelent article that I used to decide to use the (NOLOCK) hint). I'm marking this as the answer since it is actually what I did and nobody else posted it as an "answer". Thanks :)